# Where should I save a database on an Android file system

Tags: android, sqlite, filesystems, xamarin, android-file

I am writing a Android application and I am wanting to have a local SQLite database as part of my application.

Where should I store this database on the device's file system? Is there a default place to store files that are a part of an application? What do I need to take into consideration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should google first and ask questions later: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should store your database on the device internal storage. And yes, there is a default location for your database in the file system. In order to create a database file, you can create a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

This class has, among other things, a Constructor that allows you to give a name, version and `CursorFactory` object to your database file. It has also the `getWritableDatabase()` method, which will automatically create your database file and return an `SQLiteDatabase` object, from where you can insert data and execute queries.

Your recently created file will be placed in your internal app databases folder folder, usually in data/data/com.your.package.name/databases/databasename.db. In a normal situation, the user has no permissions to access this file. Unless he has rooted his phone and therefore he has root permissions. So, it is the best place to keep your database.

To check more about this, see [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) and [this also](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't care!

You should use a SQLiteOpenHelper.  It, incidentally, stores your database in /data/data/<your package name>/databases, as several of the other answerers have noted.  If you actually depend on knowing where it is, though, you might be doing it wrong.

Comment: Alright sir. Does clearing app data in settings also remove my database. If so I am terrified. I need a database that some malicious person using the phone cant just clear away.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you should use the default location supplied by `SQLiteOpenHelper`; there is however, another option. The other option (which very FEW apps use) is saving it to `(ExternalDirectory)/Android/data/com.example.app`. You should however use the default because you don't want users being able to access it.

Answer (score -1):

its better to save in data directory where user cant enter

check [data directory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)

Answer (score -1):

From Google web site:
Just like files that you save on the device's internal storage, Android stores your database in private disk space that's associated application. Your data is secure, because by default this area is not accessible to other applications

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: What if malicious person clears app data?